# Can I create multiple entry points to a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, config

In **Spring Boot**, a main class needs to be specified, which is the entry point to the app. Typically this is a simple class with a standard main  method, as follows;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringApplication {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This class is then specified as the main entry point when the application runs.

However, I want to run my code using a different main class using config to define this, And without using a different `jar`!! (I know rebuilding the jar will enable me to specify an alternative main class, but this effectively gives me two apps, not one! So, how can I do this to utilise one `jar` with two main classes and select the one to use via the Spring  **application.yml** file?

Comment: what's the purpose?

Comment: Spring Boot's entry point looks like `SpringApplication.run(className, args)`, why are you creating an instance of your own class and what's the code in there?

Comment: @AndresToilko I wanted to include CLI to SpringBoot as separate entrypoint for setup testing - faced the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer - use the CommandLineRunner interface...

So now I have two classes;

```
public class ApplicationStartupRunner1 implements CommandLineRunner {

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //implement behaviour 1 
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationStartupRunner2 implements CommandLineRunner {

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //implement behaviour 2
}
```

and how to switch between them in config..

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${app.runner}")
    private int runner;

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner getCommandLineRunner() {
        CommandLineRunner clRunner = null;
        if (runner == 1) {
            clRunner = new ApplicationStartupRunner1();
        } (else if runner == 2) {
            clRunner = new ApplicationStartupRunner2();
        } else {
            //handle this case..
        }

        return clRunner;
    }
}
```

and finally in the application.properties file, use

```
app.runner=1
```

Answer (score 3):

I would stick with the original pattern of having just one main class and main method, however within that method you could configure where you want to go.  I.e. rather than having 2 main methods and configuring which gets called make these 2 methods just normal methods, and create one main method which uses the config to determine which of your two methods get run.

Comment: Unfortunately the Spring config is not loaded until after application.run method is called, so the main method is already run before the config is known.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of jonny.l is fine.
Another very similar, but more manual/DIY solution is to get the [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), from which you can get all other things:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class);
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = context.getBean(ConfigurableEnvironment.class);
        
        String mainApp = env.getProperty("app.runner");
        if (mainApp.equals("Main1")) {
            Main1 main1 = context.getBean(Main1.class);
            main1.run();
        } else if (mainApp.equals("Main2")) {
            Main2 main2 = context.getBean(Main2.class);
            main2.run();
        }
    }
}

@Service @Lazy
public class Main1 {
    public void run() {}
}

@Service @Lazy
public class Main2 {
    public void run() {}
}
```

`@Lazy`is used to prevent those beans from loading unnecessarily automatically.